# Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin message not orientated properly on iOS devices

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

My project in ionic framework, and I add PhoneGap Toast plugin into my project. Issue comes when message not rotated on iOS devices, when device is rotated in landscape mode. Message still showing in vertical mode. but in android it working properly.

[image]

Comment: so, it's working but it doesn't have the right orientation. Open an issue on the github plugin page

Comment: I already open that question on git hub page. https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/37

Comment: So give him time to fix it, it's obviously a bug. And you should provide more information on the issue. "Not working" is not a valid issue as it's really woring, but not rotated

Comment: ya, thats right I change the change question. and I also publish the code on github.

Comment: Please check demo code on this https://github.com/rahulsalvikar777/toastPluginDemo.git

Comment: I've tested your demo project and it's working as expected. I had to allow the orientations for iPad as your demo projec wasn't rotating

Comment: Still, I got same issue on both the devices :( . And I suggest you to please check side by side this link https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/37 . Because on iPhone 6 plugin working properly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it working properly on iOS 7 and above

Comment: It's fixed now, next time provide all the details from the begining